# is it possible to hide the hancoded index.php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have few hancoded links in my site ,some thing like this

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $url.'/index.php/bla/bla1'?>"><span>Bla bla bla</span></a></li>
```

My Question is ?Is it possible to remove thoose index.php using .htaccess(putting it into the root folder) by writting this in it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So you want to use `http://site.com/bla/bla1` instead of `http://site.com/index.php/bla/bla1` ?

Comment: What does it have to do with Yii?

Comment: If you have only few hardcoded links - then just fix them by using `createUrl()`. It will remove unnessesary maintaining burden from your website.

Answer (score 0):

you can do It with jQuery,check every href attribute to match your pattern, and change it. It's not so pretty but anyway ,like:

```
$.each($('a') , function(key , value){
...
```

define your pattern here and change the url ...

```
$(value).attr('href' , newHref);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you remove "index.php" in ".htaccess".

In one of my yii sites i found this, first test it local...

```
RewriteEngine on
# redirect www to non-www (http & https)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```